# iBooks storing books in iFile not with original file names but renamed to 16 length Hex character

Tags: jailbreak, books

I store many books epub and pdf through direct downloads on my ipad into iBooks as well as copying over from iTunes. My problem is that when I view the books what I get a 16 char hex string instead of the file name using a file manager such as iFile. (Book names in the UI GUI does show correct) This is for books I copied to my ipad with iTunes where the file a moved from my PC had the correct name.

This makes locating a book hard (i have a very large book collection) if i want to us iFile and not iBooks itself to locate a book to copy and send via iFile to other devices.

Any idea how to translate those 16 char hex names displayed in iFile to the proper book name displayed in iBooks UI?

Comment: iBooks on Mac does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Download or open the file Books.plist in the root of books. This will give a list of book names with that  corresponding long string

Comment: I keep a a "Books II" folder, where every book I can get into it is stored with a human readable title. Books don't take up a lot of space, so that's not an issue. The folder makes it a LOT easier to move things onto non-Apple devices.